# How can I check method params when method call using mockito?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito

I am trying to write unit test which will test `fillA` method. I need to verify that `doSmth` calling with correctly initialized `a` fields. 
Here is example.

```
SecondClass secondClass = new SecondClass();

public void execute() {
  A a = new A();
  fillA(a);
  secondClass.doSmth(a);
}

private void fillA(A a) {
  a.setFirstField("first field");
  a.setSecondField("second field");
}

class SecondClass {
  public void doSmth(A a) {
    // doSmth
  }
}

class A {
  private String firstField;
  private String secondField;

  // getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ensure, that `secondClass` is invoked, you should use [`Mockito.verify`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#verify(T)).

> verify(): to check methods were called with given arguments
>   can use flexible argument matching, for example any expression via the [`any()`](https://mockito.github.io/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Matchers.html#any())
>   or capture what arguments where called using [`@Captor`](http://mockito.github.io/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/Captor.html) instead.

For example:

```
Mockito.verify(secondClass).doSmth(<arg>);
```

If you want to check that the `a` fields are correctly initialized, `<arg>` could be:

- an instance of A (`new A("first field", "second field")`), if A define a proper `equals`

  > Arguments passed are compared using equals() method"
- a custom `A` [`ArgumentMatcher`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/ArgumentMatcher.html)
- an [`ArgumentCaptor`](http://site.mockito.org/mockito/docs/current/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the basic structure of the test you need. You need to mock your `SecondClass` instance and inject this into your class under test. I've named your outer class as `Bar`.

This code assumes you implement a `.equals()` method on the `A` class.

```
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.verify;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.runners.MockitoJUnitRunner;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class BarTest {

  @Test
  public void testAIsCorrectlyInitialized() throws Exception {
    SecondClass secondClass = mock(SecondClass.class);
    Bar bar = new Bar();
    bar.setSecondClass(secondClass);

    A expected = new A();
    // here, populate "expected" with correct values

    bar.execute();

    // Verify call (assumes A implements a proper equals)
    verify(secondClass).doSmth(expected);
  }
}
```